# Finding a real number $k$ such that $u_n\leq k\sqrt{n}$, where $u_{n+1}=\sqrt{u_n+cn}$ and $c\geq0$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $c$ be a non-negative real number and $\left(u_n\right)_{n\geq 1}$ be the sequence defined by $u_1 = 1$ and the induction relation: $$u_{n+1}=\sqrt{u_n + cn}$$

Find a real number $k$ such that for any integer $n \geq 1$, one has $u_n \leq k\sqrt{n}$.

Comment: Do you have a candidate for $k$? Have you tried the series with a few values of $c$ and $u_1=1$, for example?

Comment: I presume $ k $ is in terms of $ c $?

Comment: Yes, i tried many things, but I can't find some k @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг

Answer (score 1):

$u_n\leq k\sqrt{n}$ grants $u_{n+1}\leq k\sqrt{n+1}$ as soon as
$$ \sqrt{u_n+cn} = \sqrt{k\sqrt{n}+c n}\leq k\sqrt{n+1} $$
i.e. as soon as
$$ k\sqrt{n} \leq k^2+(k^2-c)n. $$
It follows that any $k$ such that $k\leq k^2-c$ does the job.
 $k=\color{red}{\sqrt{c}+1}$ is a simple and effective choice.

Answer (score -1):

Show by induction, that k=c+1 is O.K.

FRED

Comment: It would improve your Answer to supply the reasoned mathematical argument you've hinted at.