# Is there a close form for this sequence $a^2_{n+1}=a_n+cn$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

> Let $c$ be a positive real number and $(a_n)_{n\geq1}$ be the sequence defined by $a_1=1$ and the recurrence relation $$a^2_{n+1}=a_n+cn$$
> $1$. Find a real number $p$ such that for any integer $n\geq1$. one has $a_n\leq p\sqrt n$
> $2$. Find an equivalent of $a_n$, when $n$ tends to infinity, of the form $a_n\sim\alpha n^\beta$ (where $\alpha, \beta$ are real number)
> $3$. Compute the limit of $a_n-\alpha n^\beta$ as n tends to infinity

I've been stuck with this problem for several hours even though I can't seem to find any clue at all.

For my approach is, I try to find the general formula for the sequence.

At first I try to manipulate around with the $nth$ term, what I try to archive here is put $\ln$ on both side so that maybe I could get it in the form of $b_{n+1}=ab_n$ but no luck. Then I take a look at the numerical $a_2, a_3,...a_5$ to see if I could get some information out of it. But I can't.

By the way, by what I observe, when one write $a_n$ in the term of many square root it looks like to be the kind of Ramanujan sequence (I might be call the name wrong but what I mean is that long sequence with many square root and sum inside).

Also by my research, I find [Mandelbrot set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mandelbrot_set)
which is kind of look the same, but I still don't know how to process.

**EDITED:**

After searching up for a bit more, I was able to find the whole problem in which have another question so I add it (the question $3$) for completeness.

As point out by @JeanMarie in the comment, there is already somebody asking [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1987038) before. But for question ($1$) only.

In the previous thread as answer by @Jack D'Aurizio, for the first part:

$a_n\leq p\sqrt{n}$ grants $a_{n+1}\leq p\sqrt{n+1}$ as soon as
$$ \sqrt{a_n+cn} = \sqrt{p\sqrt{n}+c n}\leq p\sqrt{n+1} $$
i.e. as soon as
$$ p\sqrt{n} \leq p^2+(p^2-c)n. $$
The inequality suggests that we only need to take a look at the term that have $n$ since adding more $p^2$ would guarantee to be true. So it follows that
$p\leq p^2-c$ in which we could solve and take $p=\sqrt{c}+1$ (this is simpler compare to what we would get from the actual equation and it still does its job)

Now for the second part:

I don't really get what is going on but for what I understand, since we have the inequality $$a_n\leq (\sqrt{c}+1)\sqrt{n}$$ from the previous then we could take $\alpha=\sqrt{c}+1$ and $\beta=\frac{1}{2}$?

Then for the third part we would get $0$ as the answer for the limit?

Comment: Think about it: If you could get a closed form, what's the point of *indirectly* asking about this sequence? The question could well be separated into two: One asks for the closed from given the relation; one asks for the two properties given the closed form.

Comment: This sequence is very unlikely to have closed forms.

Comment: The first question is treated here: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1987038.

Comment: @JeanMarie I've been searching for a while but can't seem to find the duplicate. How do you search for it?

Comment: I use the (very efficient !) formula searching tool https://approach0.xyz/ At first, I had no match ; I have then changed the query into $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{a_n+cn}$ which is in fact more natural :).